# Как уменьшить расстояние между двумя колонками? (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Нужно уменьшить расстояние между двумя колонками так, чтобы заголовок и его псевдоэлемент `::before` были ближе к картинке, как на фотографии ниже:[image: tesla]

Вот что получилось у меня:
[image: tesla]

Код:
HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <span id = 'firstBlock'>
    <img src="https://www.cstatic-images.com/car-pictures/xl/USC70TSC024B021001.png" alt="">
  </span>
  <span id = 'secondBlock'>
    <span id="title">Design</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

#title {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #111;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

#title::before {
  content: '';
  width: 151px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -171px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m8s3dc7k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В #container вы используете свойство justify-content: space-around; , что равномерно распределяет элементы по всей ширине блока. Используйте justify-content: center; и выставляйте отступами нужный зазор.